# How do I Loosen a Stuck Threaded Brass Fitting?

Tags: plumbing, pex, fitting, brass-fitting, old-pipes

I’m about to replace some of the brass water pipes to PEX in my basement. I bought an adapter fitting at a plumbing supply store(picture 1) and cut the cold water pipe(picture 2). I tried to remove the pipe from the old fitting in order to install the adapter (picture 3). The problem is the pipe stuck in the fitting. I used heat gun to melt the glue down but it doesn’t work. I don’t know what kind of glue the plumbers used in 1947. It’s very strong. Please give me some advice.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's not "glue" it's "pipe dope". It's designed to waterproof the threads.

Comment: Possibly a hardening product like a "Permatex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a plumber in Texas and we see that slot
The old timers used linseed oil and cement to seal those joints. I won't even waste my time with pipe wrenches because you won't unscrew the pipe. Cut the pipe close to the fitting. With a sawzall and a small cutting blade. Notch the inside of the pipe in four places and chisel it out with a small screwdriver.

Answer (score 5):

You need two pipe wrenches - one for the pipe and one for the fitting so you don’t damage the other pipes.

However, I would likely go with a solder fitting to get to what you want if that is **so** tight.

Comment: A little heat would probably soften the thread compound.

Comment: @isherwood OP mentions heat in the original post, but a louisiana spanner would probably provide more...

Comment: Thanks. Missed that. To clarify, a _lot_ of heat, like what a plumber's torch would provide. The pipe itself need to be quite warm to the touch. I suspect that the heat gun wasn't adequately implemented.

Comment: @isherwood Couldn't ***a lot*** of heat affect adjacent joints and cause those joints to start leaking unless you could re-tighten them as well?

Comment: I wouldn't think so unless they were rotated, breaking the bond. I have limited thread compound experience, though.

Comment: It's brass pipe you can solder onto, +1. Turn *nothing* with a pipe wrench or you might not get to stop.

Comment: @SolarMike A "Louisiana Spanner"?  Not from Louisiana... no idea what you're referring to....

Comment: Googled Louisiana Spanner and got thie - https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/80021/how-would-you-prevent-theft-in-a-simple-way-other-than-a-kill-switch#comment135502_80025 - the comment suggests "an oxy-actylene torch."

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a crack in the T fitting:

[image: Image of Fitting]

If so you should replace it.

Comment: True (though I think it's just a stain), but not an answer. Should've been a comment.

Comment: True, @isherwood, but it's hard to include an image in a comment. Though a link would do the trick.

Comment: No it's not (you can upload in an answer box if you like and copy the URL). And that's not an excuse to violate site rules.

Comment: I believe it is an answer.  If the fitting it cracked, then it should be replaced.  That overrides the original problem of how to remove the fitting.

Comment: A person would still need to know _how_ to replace it, which was the question. I don't think I'm being overly pedantic here.

Comment: Whatever the semantics; replace the cracked fitting. It could be cast iron at that age.

Comment: Agree with @isherwood. While this is useful information, and it tells _why_ it should be replaced, it doesn't go into any detail at all about _how_ to replace the fitting therefore it is not an "answer" _per se._ If the OP is asking how to replace it, it doesn't do much good to tell him that it needs replaced.

Comment: That's just the parting line of the casting. OP has *several thousand dollars* of brass in their house.... If it wasn't *all* brass it would've failed 60y ago.